# False Interpretation of a logical statement

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have to find a false Interpretation of $$(\forall x)[P(x) \to Q(x)] \land (\exists x)(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \to (\exists x)(P(x) \land Q(x))$$

Isn't it true that $(\forall x)[P(x) \to Q(x)]$ means $\exists x(P(x) \land Q(x))$ ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Isn't it true that ...?" NO :-(

Comment: How ? Can you explain a little ?

Comment: Consider an interpretation in $\mathbb N$ and read $Px$ as $x < 0$ and $Qx$ as $x > 0$.

Comment: Right. Got your point.

Comment: It is a very rare thing for one formula $\forall x(\psi(x))$ to be equivalent to another formula $\exists x(\varphi(x))$. It basically only happens if $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are either both tautologies or both contradictions. In fact, some sources _define_ "$\forall x$" as the symbol combination "$\lnot\exists x\lnot$". It is difficult to get rid of that first $\lnot$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because if $Q$ is a tautology (meaning that $Q(x)$ is always true, for example $Q(x) \equiv (x = x)$  then $P(x) \to Q(x)$ is always a true implication.

This, by the way, shows you that your initial logical formula is false: indeed, take $Q$ any tautology (always True), $P$ any contradiction (always False), and show that this satisfies the left part of your implication but not the right part.

Comment: That's nice. Thank you